# x-amz-content-sha256 error when post to s3 behind api gateway

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm sending the following request with the postman

```
POST https://zzz.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/v1/ HTTP/1.1
x-amz-content-sha256:c2c12939e2d6cab44a2f3ca62d3eddd8887bff81ef04b0f361e53bcca354380d
User-Agent:PostmanRuntime/7.32.2
Accept:*/*
Host:zzz.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------466405293915446238903417
Content-Length:468

----------------------------466405293915446238903417
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-content-sha256"

c2c12939e2d6cab44a2f3ca62d3eddd8887bff81ef04b0f361e53bcca354380d
----------------------------466405293915446238903417
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
Content-Type: text/plain
x-amz-content-sha256:c2c12939e2d6cab44a2f3ca62d3eddd8887bff81ef04b0f361e53bcca354380d

one more file
----------------------------466405293915446238903417--
```

I've added x-amz-content-sha256 everywhere, including the header mapping in the request integrations, but nothing helped, I tried UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD with the same result.
The API gateway responds with the well known error `x-amz-content-sha256 must be UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD, ...`

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>x-amz-content-sha256 must be UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD, STREAMING-UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD-TRAILER, STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD, STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD-TRAILER, STREAMING-AWS4-ECDSA-P256-SHA256-PAYLOAD, STREAMING-AWS4-ECDSA-P256-SHA256-PAYLOAD-TRAILER or a valid sha256 value.</Message>
<ArgumentName>x-amz-content-sha256</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>null</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>ZQPKJP1F5X4YSVRR</RequestId>
<HostId>gJHml4BJoHBpiOsk/c2PXkCXnAqohXmRlfNCLwj6RwKcuXVrhNA60nZCMlLoVbo3oYPH8QxspT4=</HostId>
</Error>
```

What should I send to the API gateway to make the POST method working?